# Adding at the end of single line by matching using shell scripts

Tags: bash, shell, sed, solaris

I have a shell script test.sh and the content is whithin the shell script i'm using exec command to run the java command

```
export T1=
exec java  -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+PrintClassHistogram 
..
dosomething
```

Now i have modify the argument dymanically to add " -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8" in solaris, and for that i'm using sed command
**to**

```
export T1
exec java  -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+PrintClassHistogram  -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
...
dosomething
```

I;m new with sed commad and it's not working properly can i have some other alternatives

```
sed   -e "s/^\(exec \java.*\)$/\1 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8/" test.sh > $test.sh.tmp
```

Comment: Why did you escape `j` in `java`.  Your command should work well if you don't escape that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this sed:

```
sed -i.bak '/exec java/s/$/-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8/' test.sh

cat test.sh
export T1=
exec java  -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+PrintClassHistogram -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
..
dosomething
```

Comment: sed  -i  '/exec java/s/$/-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8/' test.sh
sed: illegal option -- i

Comment: It seems you have very old sed. Remove `-i` as `sed '/exec java/s/$/-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8/' test.sh > _tmp && mv _tmp test.sh`